# "To do this" or "For doing this" to start explaining something?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Many questions have been asked and answered about "to + bare infinitive" vs "for + gerund" in the middle of a sentence.

However, when one wants to start explaining something, what is better? For instance:

"Now, let us focus on baking the bread.

- To do this, start by turning the oven on.", or
- For doing this, start by turning the oven on."?

Are there even better expressions?
I have not found anything concerning this situation, and I feel that the answers about the same problem but in the middle of a sentence do not apply here.

Comment: Consider adding a sample sentence/paragraph to focus the discussion.

Comment: @Lawrence I hope my example is clear enough.

Comment: I should add that I am looking for **formal** ways to write this.

Comment: I was going to say that in your examples, *To do this* sounds better. But if it's a *formal* setting, skip the first phrase altogether and jump straight in: "Start by turning the oven on ...". The chapter or section title should (I say *should* here in both senses - *the writer ought to*; and *for the reader, it is likely to*) provide a better context than "to do this" or "for doing this".

Answer (score 1):

Some expressions (They vary slightly in meaning):

- For this (one), we will start by ...
- To do this (one), we will start by ...
- When doing this (one), we will start by ...
  --*Using the present participle.*
- If you are doing this (one), we will start by ...
  --*Conditional (On the condition that you do this).*
- With this (one), we will start by
  --*This with one just emphasizes what to do, in that particular case.*

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you explain *how* they vary?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have now elaborated on how they vary